# str2num() returns an empty value

Tags: regex, matlab

I have a string variable defined by

```
data2= '{ "fromID"  1    "toID"     2    "value"     [ 20   18] }    { "fromID"     1    "toID"     3    "value"     [ 12   12] }   ';
```

I want to get rid of any text from the variable and get a one line vector:

```
[1 2 20 18 1 3 12 12]
```

I used the code below:

```
data2(regexp(data2, '["fromID", "toID", "value"]')) = []
data2(regexp(data2, '[[,],{,}]')) = []
```

and it gave me such a string

```
'1      8       20  18      1       11      12  12'
```

Its class is `char`. When I apply `[data2, OK] = str2num(data2)` I get an empty variable and the value of `OK` is 0. Are the spaces between values the problem? How do I convert it to a numerical vector?

Comment: Why not just use the regex to get the digits?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to. `data3=regexp(data2,'[0-9]');
data4=data2(data3)`. Applied this one, all spaces are gone and I am left with `1820181111212`.

Comment: I would suggest reading [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) a bit more thoroughly, there is a [`'match'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html#input_argument_d119e897024) option to return the actual matches instead of the starting indices. Using this in conjunction with `'\d+'` should function just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably easier to use the [`'match'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html#input_argument_d119e897024) outkey of [`regexp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) and match the digits directly:

```
data2= '{ "fromID"     1    "toID"     2    "value"     [ 20   18] }    { "fromID"     1    "toID"     3    "value"     [ 12   12] }   ';

out = str2double(regexp(data2, '\d+', 'match'));
```

Which returns:

```
>> out

out =

     1     2    20    18     1     3    12    12
```

If for some reason you have to use the other method, you can utilize [`sscanf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sscanf.html) to parse the resulting string:

```
data2= '{ "fromID"     1    "toID"     2    "value"     [ 20   18] }    { "fromID"     1    "toID"     3    "value"     [ 12   12] }   ';

data2(regexp(data2,'["fromID","toID","value"]'))=[];
data2(regexp(data2,'[[,],{,}]'))=[];

out = sscanf(data2, '%f');
```

Which returns the same. Note that this method returns a column vector, where the direct `regexp` method above returns a row vector.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that your use of `str2double` is preferable over the OP's use of `str2num`, since (from the docs) *"`str2num` uses the `eval` function to convert the input argument."* So if something went wrong with the string parsing then `str2num` could create some wacky behaviour!